# A crash at int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController"); in cocos2dx 2.2.3

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

My code snippet as follow:

```
void HelloWorld::gameOver()
{
CCDirector *pDirector=CCDirector::sharedDirector();
pDirector->getTouchDispatcher()->removeAllDelegates();

this->stopAllActions();

this->unscheduleUpdate();
this->unscheduleAllSelectors();

CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
CCPoint origin = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();

auto spriteEndbg1 = CCSprite::create("engbg1136.png");
spriteEndbg1->setPosition(CCPoint(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2));
this->addChild(spriteEndbg1, 5);

auto spriteTop = CCSprite::create("gameover.png");
spriteTop->setPosition(CCPoint(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height-200));
this->addChild(spriteTop, 5);

//score
auto scorebg = CCSprite::create("endtextbg.png");
scorebg->setPosition(CCPoint(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height-350));
this->addChild(scorebg, 5);
char *str = new char(5);
sprintf(str, "您的得分为：%d", scodeNum);
std::string strScore = str;
CCLabelTTF* pLabel = CCLabelTTF::create(str, "Arial", 50);
pLabel->setPosition(ccp(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2,
                        origin.y + visibleSize.height - pLabel->getContentSize().height));
this->addChild(pLabel, 5);

//try again
auto tyrAgainbg = CCSprite::create("endtextbg.png");
tyrAgainbg->setPosition(CCPoint(visibleSize.width/2, 300));
this->addChild(tyrAgainbg, 5);
CCMenuItemFont::setFontName("American Typewriter");
CCMenuItemFont::setFontSize(60);
auto closeItem = CCMenuItemFont::create("ReStart", this,
                                        menu_selector(HelloWorld::restartFn));

closeItem->setPosition(CCPoint(visibleSize.width/2, 300));
auto menu = CCMenu::create(closeItem,NULL);
menu->setPosition(ccp(0,0));
this->addChild(menu, 5);
}
```

When my project after run this function a crash appear at

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");
```

It is strange that argv is null.

The stack information shown at follow:

[image]

Anyone has encounter this kind of question?

Comment: You need to give us more information to help you; try expanding the backtrace so you can see where the crash is happening. (It's the slider in the bottom right of the Xcode window.) The crash is not actually happening in the line that is displayed. It would also help to show the log message that's being printed in the debugger. (You might need to press continue to get it to print the error if you have an exception breakpoint set.)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

From the example in the question I can't say for sure but in my case it was a partial refactoring of an `IBOutlet` instance variable name change.

IChanging IBOutlet variable names using Xcode refactoring tools can easily cause your app to get an `NSAssert` / `NSException` (aka crash) at `UIApplicationMain()`...

Xcode fails to rename the `outlet property` in the refactor -> rename...  This means you have to manually open up the .xib files where that instance variable is referenced and hand-change the names there too.

For a full visual example, see this thread and my answer in:
[Changing IBOutlet Variable Names and Crashing at UIApplicationMain ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313374/how-to-rename-the-iboutlet-property-without-lose-the-connection/46396096#46396096)