# How to rename the IBOutlet property without lose the connection

Tags: ios, xcode

I work with old project and in some part of the project, the naming convention is not good so I want to change it.
For example:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnRequestCode;
rename it to -> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *requestCodeButton;
```

I know that I can delete the `IBOutlet` then reconnect but it may take many time and easy make error if careless

Any safe and fast way to do it?

I have tried Refactor -> Rename but it doesn't work and give me an warning

[image]

Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is what I usually do

1. Right Click the IBOutlet name,then selected **Find Selected Text in Workspace**

[image]

2. Click find,then selected **replace**

[image]

3.Replace to the name you want

[image]

4.You can click **Replace All** if you are sure. You can also to click preview to Replace every single change

[image]

Comment: This is a surprisingly powerful tool in Xcode that I never knew about. Thank you for saving me so much headache!

Answer (score 13):

## Xcode 9, Refactor > Rename

New in Xcode 9 you can rename an outlet (or action) in the code and storyboard at the same time.

***DISCLAIMER:** This feature only works in Xcode 9 (released September 2017) and above. Make sure to backup your project before using it. After making outlet name changes, test the affected screen(s) to make sure there are not issues. I tested this in a sample Objective C project successfully but it could cause problems in existing, more complex projects.

To rename an outlet...

### 1. Navigate to outlet in the header file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnRequestCode;
```

### 2. Right click on outlet, select **"Refactor > Rename..."**.

[image: Right click on outlet]

### 3. Change the outlet name

### 4. Select the "Rename" button or the Enter key

[image: Change the outlet name]

### The outlet is renamed in the code and storyboard

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *requestCodeButton;
```

Comment: This exact approach just cost me an egregious amount of debug time.  In rolling through a gross number of formatting and naming refactoring efforts that had no bearing on code logic or syntax, I ended up with a non-functional project. It took nearly 8 hrs of walking changes back in and testing each item of minutia before I found that the name change of an IBOutlet caused the app to unceremoniously crash at UIApplicationMain() without ever touching my code.

Comment: @WilliamCerniuk, I am sorry this rename feature caused trouble for you. Before posting this, I created a sample Objective C project and renamed an outlet successfully. I have used it successfully in existing Swift projects. Based on your experience I am going to add a disclaimer to this answer. This is a new feature of Xcode 9 and it sounds like it does not always work right.

Comment: I have not worked in Swift to any great degree. It could be the that the routine that refactors changes the '.xib' file in Swift but not in Objective C, or other languages. It was definitely not your fault, it was Apple's Xcode defect that cost me roughly 6 hrs of tracking back and figuring out how it could crash before it even hit my code. Refactoring should have worked right.

Answer (score 2):

I put my two cents in. I tried to refactor several similar IBOutlet-s and ended to complete successfully only one - the first one. [image]

All others outlets of this type throw me the error on refactoring:
[image]

Project and XCode reloading doesn't solve the problem. I checked *.xib source - the first one is fine:
[image]
My XCode ver 9.2(9C40b)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xcode Version 9.0 (*release* 9A235 or earlier beta) and you don't want to crash at `UIApplicationMain()` you will need to perform the following steps in order to rename an `IBOutlet` instance variable. (see below)

**Steps**:

1. Right-click the outlet instance variable
2. Select "Refactor -> Rename..."
3. Enter a new name Change all of them

do

4. Right-click the related '.xib' file (or files) in project file list
5. Select "Open As -> Source Code" (it will show you the XML then...)
6. Search and replace old variable name with new in .xib

while ( untouched related .xib files exist)

I wasted hours trying to figure out why the app was crashing in `UIApplicationMain()` after doing some mass refactoring of variable names. No logic changes, just hours of documenting, cleaning up structure for readability and just cleaning up names... not worth testing normally but when I decided to run.. BOOM

As it turns out, the (ahem) "release" of Xcode 9 does not manage to actually *refactor* IBOutlet instance variable names so you relegated to hand-jamming the .xib files. *True refactoring* would make all the necessary changes in the project...

Here is a regression tested example of how and what to do.

**Example:**

Select the `IBOutlet` instance variable, then right-click, select Refactor -> Rename... :

**(step 1 and 2)**
[image: Refactor -> Rename...]

Now change the name. (for the example from `textFieldController` to `editTextFieldController`) :

**(step 3)**
[image]

Now for the critical part that Xcode neglects, change the custom outlet property in the XML:

**(steps 4, and 5)**
[image]

and then find the original variable (eg `textFieldController`) and change it to the new variable name (eg `editTextFieldController`)

**(step 6)**
[image: Hand edit of outlet property in xib]

... and then when you compile and run, it doesn't throw an exception / assertion in `UIApplicationMain()` ...

Comment: This is now Radar # 34638052