# UIApplicationMain method crashing in iOS 10

Tags: ios, crash, segmentation-fault, ios10.3

My application is somehow crashing on `UIApplicationMain` method for `iOS 10.3.1` devices.

> It indicates a **SIGSEGV: SEGV_ACCERR** crash.

This is what I`ve got of logging data so far:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001943afbd0 objc_msgSend + 12
1   CoreFoundation 0x0000000182b7bf6c ___forwarding___ + 436
2   CoreFoundation 0x0000000182a7eccc __forwarding_prep_0___ + 88
3   CoreFoundation 0x0000000182b7e100 __invoking___ + 140
4   CoreFoundation 0x0000000182a7a2fc -[NSInvocation invoke] + 292
5   WebCore 0x000000019148aefc HandleDelegateSource() + 116
6   CoreFoundation 0x0000000182b30240 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
7   CoreFoundation 0x0000000182b2f4e4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 260
8   CoreFoundation 0x0000000182b2d594 __CFRunLoopRun + 708
9   CoreFoundation 0x0000000182a592d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
10  GraphicsServices 0x000000018c26f6fc GSEventRunModal + 164
11  UIKit 0x000000018761efac UIApplicationMain + 1484
!   12  my_app_name 0x00000001000c9954 main (main.m:14)
13  libdyld.dylib 0x0000000194a1aa08 start + 0
```

And this is the method:

```
// If nil is specified for principalClassName, the value for NSPrincipalClass from the Info.plist is used. If there is no
// NSPrincipalClass key specified, the UIApplication class is used. The delegate class will be instantiated using init.
UIKIT_EXTERN int UIApplicationMain(int argc, char *argv[], NSString * __nullable principalClassName, NSString * __nullable delegateClassName);
```

Any ideas on how should I debug this kind of invalid memory reference error?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly caused by a mismatch between an `IBOutlet` instance variable that was renamed and the corresponding .xib file that has the old name buried in the XML?

For an in-depth example of the defect in Xcode refactoring that causes the app to crash in `UIApplicationMain()` before executing any of your code:

[IBOutlet Name Change Causing Crash at UIApplicationMain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313374/how-to-rename-the-iboutlet-property-without-lose-the-connection/46396096#46396096)